# Debugging a native dll using rundll32.exe , fail to load symbols

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, rundll32

I'm writing a native dll that is due to run with `rundll32.exe` (that is obligated by our clients). I've using `VS`'s debugging properties to define:

```
Command: c:\windows\system32\rundll32.exe
Command Argument: $(TargetPath) , ENTRY_POINT
```

where `ENTRY_POINT` is an exported function of my dll, that obey the `rundll32.exe` interface.

This setup calls my function , but won't load any symbols and thus won't trigger any break point. I've learned that my  function was called only after placing a call to `MessageBox` at its entrance.

when I use my own container application (just an `exe` calling `Loadlibrary` , `GetProcAddress` and the `ENTRY_POINT` function itself) all break points are triggered, and a step-by-step debugging is possible as usual.

what can cause that behavior?

Comment: You are debugging the process *rundll32.exe*, and Visual Studio does not know that this process will eventually load a .dll that is the result of compiling the current solution. You cannot set breakpoints using the source code editor. The alternative is to use [`DebugBreak`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679297.aspx), if a debugger is attached ([`IsDebuggerPresent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680345.aspx)).

Comment: In old visual studio (6.0) there was an option to specify additional DLLs that can be debugged. This is not seen in VS2010, 12 etc. Have you got the DLL and PDB in the same folder? That should work normally. Another workaround would be that you could put a sleep after the DLL's entry function and attach the debugger to the rundll process quickly during this time.

Comment: @IInspectable But OP is setting debug properties of a DLL project by running an EXE which will load the DLL that he just compiled in debug mode. Break points should fire...

Comment: @IInspectable Your idea showed me that the debugger was not attached automatically, which now also makes sense to me. I used PermanentGuest idea to sleep and manully attach. so now `DebugBreak()` triggers the `VS` debugger, but still no symbols loaded , and the first `F11` click  sends me to assembly. Also , I've checked and `.pdb`'s are on the same directory as the binaries.

Comment: @friedrich Did you run *rundll32.dll* under a debugger? If so, `IsDebuggerPresent` should return `TRUE` in your .dll. Using your strategy, you should be able to right-click a method in the callstack and load symbols from there. For diagnostics make sure you have enabled source server support and have it print diagnostic messages (Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General).

Comment: @IInspectable Yes , I have run it under a debugger.

Comment: You probably should [abandon rundll32 altogether](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/01/04/10382242.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In short:** All problems arose due to debugging a `32Bit` dll in a `64Bit` environment.

As can be seen from original question, and side issues mentioned in comments, I had few problems here:

1. Debugger is not present in a process it has allegedly launched.
2. When manually attached, symbols were not loaded.
3. When hitting "Break All" process apeared to be deadloack.

The reason is as mention the dll being `32Bit` while debugger is `64Bit`. The path to `rundll32.exe` interpernted as the `64Bit` version. That normally causes `WOW64` to launch a sub-process of the `32Bit` version - hereby different process thus debugger not present.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

The MessageBox() gives you enough rope to troubleshoot this problem.  When it displayed, use Debug + Break All to break into the debugger.  Next, use Debug + Windows + Modules, locate the DLL in the list.  Right-click it and select "Symbol Load Information".  You get a list of all the directories where the debugger searched for your PDB file.  Make sure it is present in one of them.

Fwiw, your Command Arguments setting isn't kosher.  It should be `"$(TargetPath)" ENTRY_POINT`.  Double quotes to avoid trouble with spaces in the path name, no comma.